# Using generics to make an algorithm work on lists of "something" instead of only String's

Tags: c#, generics

I have a small algorithm which replaces the position of characters in a String:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String pairSwitchedStr = pairSwitch("some short sentence");
        Console.WriteLine(pairSwitchedStr);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static String pairSwitch(String str)
    {
        StringBuilder pairSwitchedStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int position = 0; position + 1 < str.Length; position += 2)
        {
            pairSwitchedStringBuilder.Append((char)str[position + 1]);
            pairSwitchedStringBuilder.Append((char)str[position]);
        }
        return pairSwitchedStringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

I would like to make it as generic as possible, possibly using Generics. What I'd like to have is something which works with:

- Anything that is built up using a list of instances.
- Including strings, arrays, linked lists

I suspect that the solution must use generics as the algorithm is working on a list of instances of T (there T is ... something). Version of C# isn't of interest, I guess the solution will be nicer if features from C# version >2.0 is used.

I ended up with: (Where I fixed the error in the above code, it didn't handle odd lengths correctly)

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> switchSubstitutionCipher<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        bool even = false;
        T lastItem = default(T);

        foreach (T element in input)
        {
            if (even) {
                yield return element;
                yield return lastItem;
            }

            even = !even;
            lastItem = element;
        }
        if (even)
            yield return lastItem;
    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to define what the generic version of this would do. It looks pretty string-specific right now.

Comment: I agree, I don't understand what this is supposed to do other than when working on just strings. If you want a more "modern" way of doing this, you could always use an Extension Method: `public string PairSwitch(this String str) { // your code }`.

Comment: I want to take an ordered list and change the order of the objects. In the above example each "object" is a char (I know it's a primitive) and I'm just changing the order of them in an arbitary way. I thought there might be a generic way to do it and it's just to give me some ideas on how generics may be used in C#.

Comment: Also I know about the bug in my example above. But I don't feel like correcting it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    private static IEnumerable<T> pairSwitch<T>(IEnumerable<T> input)
    {
        T current = default(T);     // just to satisfy compiler
        bool odd = true;
        foreach (T element in input)
        {
            if (odd) current = element;
            else
            {
                yield return element;
                yield return current;
            }
            odd = !odd;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = "Hello";
        string result = new string(pairSwitch(test).ToArray());
```

Benefits:

1. Lazy evaluation - which might be important for big lists
2. String implementation is handled using IEnumerable implementation.

Comment: Wow, two late responses at the same time with virtually the same solution. Even the same boolean name. +1

Comment: You should probably change the T current = input.FirstOrDefault() to just T current = default(T);  No need to enumerate through the input in the event doing so is expensive.

Comment: @Kleinux, true, although finding the first element would have been cheap.  Shame the complier's static analysis isn't smarter really.

Comment: You replicated my bug too. :-)

Comment: @Binary255 - how so?  In the original current was initialized and it handled odd length input

Comment: It looks to me like it can't handle a single character String, nothing is output as odd will be true. My original algoritm has the same problem. I haven't tested the code as it looked obvious. So you are saying it works?

Answer (score 9):

Strings, in C#, are conceptually very different than an array or linked list.  Although a string does implement `IEnumerable<Char>`, it is an immutable class, so you can't work with it like an `IList<T>` or `Array`.

I would recommend leaving your string implementation, then adding a generic implementation for any `IList<T>`:

```
private static IList<T> pairSwitch<T>(IList<T> original)
{
    List<T> results = new List<T>(original.Count);

    for (int i=0;i<original.Count-1;i+=2)  // Using -1 to make sure an odd number doesn't throw...
    {
        results.Add(original[i+1]);
        results.Add(original[i]);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you could use something like this:

```
public static class SwitchUtilities
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> PairSwitch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        T lastItem = default(T);
        bool odd = true;

        foreach(T value in source)
        {
            if(odd)
            {
                lastItem = value;
                odd = false;
            }
            else
            {
                yield return value;
                yield return lastItem;

                odd = true;
            }        
        }
    }
}
```

This would work to switch pairs of any `IEnumerable<T>` sequence, which would include string. The only issue here would be that you would get back an `IEnumerable<char>` rather than a `string`, but this is easily corrected with:

```
string value = new String("some short sentence".PairSwitch().ToArray());
```

Comment: Compiler will think lastitem is an unassigned variable here (even though it isn't).

Comment: @Hightech: I initialize `lastItem` to `default(T)`.

Comment: Yeah, that fixes it. But it's still one line longer :-)

Comment: @Hightechrider: True, but yours isn't an extension method ;)

Comment: You replicated my bug too. :-)